# require is not a function when tried to load require in define([])

Tags: jquery, requirejs

I am learning basics of requireJS . I tried to load my html code to the index.html #container DOM. But I have got an error

> "require is not a function"

this is my code:
**1. Index.html**

```
<script data-main="js/app" src="js/require.js"></script>
```

**2.app.js**

```
require(['../page1'], function(View){    
var v = new View();
v.init();  });
```

**3.page1.js**

```
define([], function (require) {
 var view1 = function(){
 this.init = function(){
 template = require('page1.html');
 $("#container").html(template);
 }
};
return view1;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should drop the empty dependency array in your `define`, like this:

```
define(function (require) {
```

If you do this, RequireJS will interpret that you want to use the CommonJS-style `require` call, and will automatically pass the `require` function as the first parameter of your callback. When you have the empty array, RequireJS interprets your module as a plain AMD module and does not pass anything to it.

See [this section](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#cjsmodule) of the documentation. The documentation shows `function(require, exports, module)` but `function(require)` works just as well if you do not need to use `exports` and `module`.

And you should use the [`text` plugin](https://github.com/requirejs/text) to load your HTML, otherwise it will be interpreted as JavaScript and obviously this won't work. Once it is installed, change `require('page1.html')` to `require('text!page1.html')`.

Comment: Not working. I changed  like this "define(function (require) { "  it gives script error and still it comes with the extension of js.           require.js:1958 GET file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/test/assets/page1.html.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: That's a different problem. I've edited my answer to add something about it.

Comment: I want to write a onclick listener to a button in page1.js . i have wrote like this in the init().. $('.lsubmit').on('click', function(e) {
                            View1.mynewmethod(e);
                           });

Comment: This looks like a new question. Once you've researched it thoroughly, please post it as a new question on SO with all the code necessary to reproduce the problem.